# Can I create my customized shadowContextWrapper in robolectric?

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, robolectric

I run robolectric unit test on my android project.

My environment is :
robolectric 2.3 and the version of android.jar is 19

When I start an activity in my test case, I get the nullPointetException.
After tracing my code, I find it is caused by sendOrderBroadcast.
since ShadowContextWrapper doesn't implement sendOrderBroadcast(...).

```
this.activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(myActivity.class).create().get();
```

To solve the problem, I implement the function in my contextWrapper shadow by extending ShadowContextWrapper as following.

```
@Implements(ContextWrapper.class)
public class myShadowContextWrapper extends ShadowContextWrapper {

    @Implementation
    public void sendOrderedBroadcast( Intent intent, String receiverPermissions ){
        getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
    @Implementation
    public void  sendOrderedBroadcast (Intent intent, String receiverPermission, BroadcastReceiver resultReceiver, 
            Handler scheduler, int initialCode, String initialData, Bundle initialExtras) {
        getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

}
```

I got another error message.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>
> attempted to invoke public void
>   com.example.myShadowContextWrapper.sendOrderedBroadcast
>   (android.content.Intent,java.lang.String,android.content.BroadcastReceiver,android.os.Handler,int,java.lang.String,android.os.Bundle)
>   on instance of class org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowApplication, but
>   ShadowApplication doesn't extend myShadowContextWrapper

It seems robolectric doesn't replace shadowContextWrapper to myShadowContextWrapper so shadowApplication still inherits to shadowContextWrapper.

I also try to implement "myShadowApplication" and extend my myShadowContextWrapper,
but error message shows that myShadowApplication can't be convert to ShadowApplication.

It is impossible to let inherit ShadowApplication and myShadowContextWrapper in the mean time in Java .

Comment: Can you post a stack trace?